# insert new html code in the middle of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

i want to insert new html code in the middle ng-repeat, but i don't know how.. i already try using append but it can't append.
Here's some example of my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in records">{{x}}

<div id="new_div"></div>
</h1>

<script>

    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.records = [
        "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "Berglunds snabbköp",
        "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "Ernst Handel",
      ]

        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            $scope.AppendText();
        });

  $scope.AppendText = function() {
   var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#new_div' ) );
   myEl.append('</div><div class="detail_area"><p class="detail_area_text"> Find out more about the products you want in a detailed search method.</p><div class="detail_area_button_div"><button class="detail_area_button_text"><span>Detail search filter <span style="color: #81abde;font-size: 50px;margin-left: 4px;"> > </span></span></button></div></div><div class="container container_page">');
  }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Don't ever modify the DOM from a controller. Modify your template. Also, an id is supposed to be unique. You can't have several divs with the same ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track your repeat by index. show your record using `{{x}}`. Then check your condition in `ng-if` to show the new div. Yyou will have the iteration number in `$index` starting from 0.

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in records track by $index">{{x}}

        <div ng-if="$index === 1" class="detail_area">
         <p class="detail_area_text"> Find out more about the products you want in a detailed search method.</p>
    <div class="detail_area_button_div">
    <button class="detail_area_button_text">
    <span>Detail search filter  </span>
    <span style="color: #81abde;font-size: 50px;margin-left: 4px;"> </span></button></div></div><div class="container container_page">
        <div id="new_div"></div>
  </div>
           </h1>
```

Comment: i need to insert it just once, maybe after 2 repeat?

Comment: You need this to be shown once? at which iteration exactly?

Comment: maybe like this:
repeat 1
repeat 2
new div
repeat 3

Comment: Like alternatively??repeat1 repeat 2 new div repeat 3 repeat 4 new div repeat 5 repeat 6 new div. Is this your reqmnt?

Comment: nope, just once, like i said before, 1 2 new div 3 4 5 6 and so on

Comment: then my answer will do. feel free to ask for any queries.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! it really help, i don't know that we can track ng-repeat using index :D

Comment: track by $index is actually not needed to have access to the $index. The $index variable is available in any ng-repeat.

Comment: @JBNizet ... oh, did not know that. Thanks for the new info. so you are saying, we can get the index of iteration inside the ng- repeat without track ?

Comment: Yes. you can also use $first, $last, $odd, $even, $middle.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you must use attrib `class` instead of the `id` of the `div`, because you should have an only one `id` per element.

You can use the `$timeout` function instead of listening to `$viewContentLoaded` events.

You can have something similar to:

```
    ...
    "Ernst Handel",
  ]
$scope.AppendText = appendText;

$timeout($scope.AppendText);

function appendText() {
    var myEl = angular.element...
```

Or even better:

```
$timeout(appendText);

function appendText() {
   var myEl = ...
```

Comment: What is he asking, what are you saying.?

Comment: He asked for a way to insert new html code in the middle of a ng-repeat block.

It was just a way reusing his code. I just wanted to help.

Comment: But never suggest bad practices. He's using AngulaJS. so suggest best practices in angulaJS.